# if statement from ajax output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im comparing the output of ajax call from php to a string. but the if statement doesnt work as expected. what am i doing wrong? the output is Good. but it triggers the else statement. not the if

```
.done(function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
    if (msg == "Good") {
        alert("it says good");
    } else {
        window.location.href = "logout.php";
    }
})
```

Comment: Try `msg.trim() === 'Good'`

Comment: can you log it console to make sure the output is Good (vs good or anything else)?

Comment: @Tushar is it better to compare with `==` because they dont need to be same type as long as they are same it will pass?just want to clear..

Comment: @guradio From the code it is clear that the response is always **string**. Thus using `===` is better.